# Pass models as arguments

Tags: json, flutter, function, dart

In my project, I use the same function over and over again with small differences to get data from firebase, but they use different models, and couldn't figure out how to tell the function to use the correct model.

This is the function that I need to call:

```
  getDataFromFirebase(String firebaseArray, String document) async {
    _instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    _localModel = [];
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
        _instance!.collection('collection');
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await collectionReference.doc(document).get();
    var data = snapshot.data() as Map;
    var localData;
    localData = data[firebaseArray] as List<dynamic>;
    localData.forEach((element) {
      _localModel.add(model1.fromJson(element));
    });

    return _localModel;
  }
```

This is the first model class:

```
class Model1 {
  String name;
  Model1({
    required this.name,
  });
  factory Model1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Model1(
      name: json['name']
    );
  }
}
```

and model 2 class can have different/more keys:

```
class Model2 {
  String name;
  int age;
  Model2({
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
  });
  factory Model2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Model2(
      name: json['name'],
      age: json['age'],
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this issue or I do have to write one function for every method?

P.S feel free to ask for any details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, with the help of generics:

```
Future<List<TModel>> getDataFromFirebase<TModel>(
      String firebaseArray,
      String document,
      TModel Function(Map<String, dynamic>) converter) async {
    final instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final localModel = <TModel>[];
    final collectionReference = instance!.collection('collection');
    final snapshot = await collectionReference.doc(document).get();
    final data = snapshot.data() as Map;
    final localData = data[firebaseArray] as List<dynamic>;

    localData.forEach((element) {
      localModel.add(converter(element));
    });

    return localModel;
}
```

`_instance` and `_localModel` seemed to be instance variables. I made them local variables, there is no good reason to have instance variables in this method.

Call it like this:

```
final models1 = await getDataFromFirebase<Model1>("?", "?", Model1.fromJson);

final models2 = await getDataFromFirebase<Model2>("?", "?", Model2.fromJson);
```

Obviously, replace the two `"?"` with your parameters, I have no idea what you pass here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out, the 2 parameters are 2 strings to define the path to the document: document is for the document name and firebaseArray is the name of the array inside the document, I'll update the question!